# Nginx redirection to Phoenix loses authorization header

Tags: nginx, redirect, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix Framework app deployed with Cloud Run with multiple clients using it.

I want to move the deployment to Computer Engine because of Cloud Run background task limitation, but I don't want to force clients to update their apps (i.e. backend url).

So I though I could deploy a Ngnix instance in Cloud Run that redirects everything to Compute Engine.

The problem is that I use an authorization request header that does not reach Phoenix connection. I've tried it with a different server (a Python simpleserver) and it receives every header properly.

So, the question is. Does Phoenix Framework filters out some request headers if they come from a  redirection?

The header is:
`{"authorization", "Bearer XXX"}`

ngixn.conf is simply:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 http://0.0.0.0:4000$request_uri;
}
```

An inspect of `conn.req_headers` for:

```
$curl -L --location --request GET 'http://localhost:80' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'other: whatever'  \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
--data-raw ''`
```

Inspection gives:

```
[
  {"accept", "*/*"},
  {"content-type", "application/json"},
  {"host", "0.0.0.0:4000"},
  {"other", "whatever"},
  {"user-agent", "curl/7.54.0"}
]
```

If a curl directly to the Phoenix server app with:

```
curl -L --location --request GET 'http://localhost:4000' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'other: whatever'  \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
--data-raw ''`
```

We got:

```
[
  {"accept", "*/*"},
  {"authorization", "Bearer XXXX"},
  {"content-length", "0"},
  {"content-type", "application/json"},
  {"host", "localhost:4000"},
  {"other", "whatever"},
  {"user-agent", "curl/7.54.0"}
]
```

***Edited***

Python server does not receive authorization header either.

Direct request to server:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020 07:22:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
other: whatever
Authorization: Bearer XXXX
Content-Length: 0
```

Request redirected through Nginx:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020 07:22:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Host: 0.0.0.0:4000
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
other: whatever
```

So I guess Nginx is 'capturing' auth header and does not let it through

Comment: If the python server receives the headers, then so should the phoenix application. Are you sure `get_req_header(conn, "authorization")` returns nothing? Anything interesting when you inspect `conn.req_headers`?

Comment: I've added examples into the main post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature in curl. If a request gets redirected to a different hostname, then any `Authorization` header is going to be removed in the second request in order not to leak credentials to an unrelated server.  (You're making a request to `localhost:80`, but the redirect location is `0.0.0.0:4000`, so that counts as a different hostname.)

You can get curl to forward the `Authorization` header by using the `--location-trusted` option instead of `-L`.

(Though it's odd that you're seeing this with curl 7.54.0 - according to [this security advisory](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/CVE-2018-1000007.html), curl 7.54.0 should behave as you expect it to, and only 7.58.0 and higher have this protection feature.)

Comment: You made my day! It works as expected with `--location-trusted`. Now I'm having the same issue with Postman, but you completely clarified that the 'problem' is in the client not in Nginx