# Intercept img src for adding Authorization header with service worker in Vue 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, service-worker

I want to show a private image served by Laravel. Since Laravel is working as an API any request must be done with Authorization header containing a Bearer token.

I'm working with Quasar, but I guess that it doesn't matter at all (unless Quasar has an proper way to do this)

I'm aware that I could attach the token in URL but it doesn't look pretty good, so I'd like to use service workers to intercept requests.

In my Vue component I have this

```js
<template>
   <img :src="file" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  setup(props, context) {
    const file = 'http://localhost:8888/files/stream/watermark.png'

    onMounted(async () => {
      await navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/service-worker.js', { scope: 'http://localhost:9999/files/stream/' })
        .then(registration => {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        })
    })

    return {
       file
    }
  }
</script>
```

My service-worker.js

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(customHeaderRequestFetch(event))
})

function customHeaderRequestFetch(event) {
    // decide for yourself which values you provide to mode and credentials
    const newRequest = new Request(event.request, {
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer PyIlosdka73Jksdjklasd...'
      }
    })
    return fetch(newRequest)
}
```

As soon as component mounts, console log shows

```
ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:  http://localhost:9999/files/stream/
```

But i still have an 401 response error from Laravel because Authorization header is not sent

```
Request Headers
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:8888
Referer: http://localhost:9999/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Any advice about how to solve this or use any other alternative will be appreciated.

EDIT: Just in case, I'm using docker with nginx and this is the config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    client_max_body_size 32M;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    location /storage {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is http://localhost:8888/files/stream/watermark.png returned to you if authorized, an image or a json?

Comment: It returns an image using Laravel's  `response()->file()` method

Comment: i answered with asumption an image as return, please check and give it a shot

Comment: Is you application behind a nginx proxy or similar? I have been having the same problem with a wordpress setup where we are using a nginx reverse proxy and so far I think it is related to the nginx configuration.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Well, in fact I'm using docker with nginx, but since I'm new in both I couldn't confirm if nginx is working as a proxy. Basically I'm doing vue js > nginx > laravel. I've updated my question to show the nginx conf

Comment: @Luciano - my guess is that this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634788/nginx-redirection-to-phoenix-loses-authorization-header

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a service worker just for that. Use fetch API tu fetch the image url and send token header, then convert blop to base64
here is my way with composition API

```
<script setup>
import {onMounted,ref} from 'vue'
const imgURL =ref('')

onMounted(()=>{
  fetch('https://miro.medium.com/max/3150/0*4FYDBk1GzfynMjCI.',{
      headers: {
    }
  }).then(resp => resp.blob()).then(blob => {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob) 
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = reader.result  
        imgURL.value = base64data              
        console.log(base64data)
    }
})
})
</script>
```

And in your templae

```
<img :src="imgURL"/>
```

here we define imgURL as a ref so we can bind it to the `src` via `:src`, then we use fetch api with header as second parameter, read it [here](https://reqbin.com/code/javascript/ricgaie0/javascript-fetch-api-example). May be it will be a bit different if using Quasar since i dont know what version of vue do quasar use, but you can figure the main idea from my explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware about this method. Also attaching the bearer token in the image URL as a parameter would be enough for parsing the token in the API and returning the file.
But I see 2 issues with your solution: first, you will get a 33% larger image because of base64 encode. Second, you need a lot of code just for sending headers. Thinking in scalability, having a worker that intercepts requests for fetching images will help to have a clean code.